# Git blame fails with message: fatal: internal error in blame::find_origin (D)

Tags: git

We noticed that using `git blame` on a file in our repository fails with the above-mentioned message. I've traced the origin of the message to https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/blame.c#L1320 and the character (D) seems to indicate that the diff has a [deleted status](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/diff.h#L559)

I'm not exactly sure what this means. I would like to repair our repository so that we can blame the file again.

Comment: This looks like a bug in `git blame`. That should be fixed, not your repository. Can you send a report to the Git mailing list `git@vger.kernel.org` and provide a repository that shows the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`git fsck` reported duplicate entries in some trees. We fixed that, and then `git blame` started working again. We follow the procedure described in the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344067/git-fsck-duplicateentries-contains-duplicate-file-entries-cannot-push-to-git), using `git fast-export` to export and import the repository to get our duplicate entries fixed.

Comment: Note that duplicate entries in a tree object are themselves an internal bug. I saw reports of this about a year ago, that seemed to be tied to MacOS, but then the reports stopped happening, as if there was some sort of broken version of Git for Mac for a short while.